# Is there a way to shorten an Excel OR function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a nested OR function to look for 6 possible titles across 4 columns and I am trying to see if there is a way to shorten the formula.

```
=IF(OR($G2="ABC",$G2="DEF",$G2="GHI",$G2="JKL",$G2="MNO",$G2="PQRS",$L2="ABC",$L2="DEF",$L2="GHI",$L2="JKL",$L2="MNO",$L2="PQRS",$P2="ABC",$P2="DEF",$P2="GHI",$P2="JKL",$P2="MNO",$P2="PQRS",$T2="ABC",$T2="DEF",$T2="GHI",$T2="JKL",$T2="MNO",$T2="PQRS"),"Group 1","Group 2")
```

Comment: I am using index in single string with separators in such cases, but in higher languages. And there is also possibility to use user defined VBA functions similar to these general.

Comment: are the strings all different or is the same 6 each cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},$G2,$L2,$P2,$T2),{"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS"},0)))>0,"Group 1","Group 2")
```

OR

```
=IF(OR($G2={"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS"},$L2={"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS"},$P2={"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS"},$T2={"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS"}),"Group 1","Group 2")
```

The second depending on one's version may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=IF(OR(INDEX(2:2,N(IF(1,{7,12,16,20})))={"ABC";"DEF";"GHI";"JKL";"MNO";"PQRS"}),"Group 1", "Group 2")
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
= "Group "&2-OR(T(OFFSET(G2,,{0,5,9,13}))={"ABC";"DEF";"GHI";"JKL";"MNO";"PQRS"})
```

and the same advice to confirm by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter for some Excel versions.

Answer (score 0):

Another one with array formula :

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH({"ABC","DEF","JKL","GHI","MNO","PQRS"},TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,G2,L2,P2,T2)),0))>0,"Group1","Group2")
```